# Creating trading robot with Python and ByBit api

Tags: cloud, trading, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, python-bybit

I am very new into **programming with Python** and **running web applications**,so wanted to make a little **learn roadmap** for my project with **next requirements** :

1.This bot should **monitor my email box** for emails from **Trading View** which will contain buy/sell **alerts** for certain tool, and then **send web requests to ByBit** to place my orders

2.In future i would like to make for myself some **android application** that will work as a **control panel for my robot**,it will perform enabling/disabling trading strategies, withdrawing money from ByBit and other activities.

What should **I learn in Python** to build such robot and **host it on some cloud servers** like Azure?
Is there any **alternative way to perform actions** that i explained **without hosting some Python code** on cloud servers?

Currently I am learning **Pandas** framework, because I've seen many developers use it for practically everything

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use email from pinescript to send webrequest to bybit : email are subject to delivery problems (spam, delays ...)

You should use the webhook functionality of the tradingview alert to send a request (with a json message from pinescript) to one of your server which will then be able to send an API order to Bybit.

TradingView Alert with WeebHook => your server (with python code to understand the json message) => API Bybit